# CSS Jquery input text without Parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

**CSS input text without Parent div**

Hi Guys, I need remove this  `<div id="input_container">` can I have the code bellow without that div around? and have the same result?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/930yrzqa/6/

**I would like just have this:**

```
<input type="text" class="input-test">
<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/36-slim-icons/87/calender.png" id="input_img">
```

```css
#input_container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 200px;
}

#input_img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.input-test {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  width: 169px;
  height: 34px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  color: $black;
  //background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/2LGbUV2.png);
  background-position: 130px 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_container">
  <input type="text" class="input-test">
   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/36-slim-icons/87/calender.png" id="input_img">
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do this with just html and CSS; though you might emulate the presentation - so it appears as if the outer element was removed - successfully with just CSS. It seems more likely, though, depending on your desired end result, that JavaScript would be required (or a server side language to remove the element before the html is sent to the client device).

Comment: this is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/930yrzqa/6/ , can be done with jquery

Comment: Just remove the `width: 100%` from `.input-test {`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/930yrzqa/10/  Do you want this

Comment: @noob-fella, did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the image in relation to itself - and place it over the input box:

```
#input_img {
  position: relative;
  left: 190px; 
  bottom: 27px;
}
```

```css
.input-test {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 34px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#input_img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  
  /* adjust as you need */
  left: 190px; 
  bottom: 27px;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" class="input-test">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/36-slim-icons/87/calender.png" id="input_img">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect with only the input element. You don't need the image element. :)

```css
#input_container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 200px;
}

#input_img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.input-test {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  width: 169px;
  height: 34px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.input-test{
  background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/36-slim-icons/87/calender.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="input-test">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do with jquery, remove the div and do this:

```
$( "input" ).wrap( "<div id='input_container'></div>" );
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/930yrzqa/7/

Comment: This adds the div again, the OP wants it without.